# How to use authentication with different table in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a new model and stored data in that table.
**If I use the `authenticate` method, it checks the `auth_user` table for the authentication and not my table. I'm using `PostgreSQL` for the backend.**
How to authenticate using a table which I created.
I am a beginner in Django.

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class register(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mob=models.BigIntegerField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```py
# views.py
def registeruser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        mob=request.POST['mob']
        password=request.POST['password1']
        password1=request.POST['password2']
        password=hashers.make_password(password)
        objects=register(username=username, password=password, mob=mob)
        objects.save()
        return render(request, "home.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "home.html")

def loginuser(request):
    usern=request.POST['username']
    passw=request.POST['password']
    user=auth.authenticate(request, username=usern, password=passw)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return render(request, 'userpage.html', {'username': usern})
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as a screenshot. Paste it as a text instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want django to use your custom user model, you need to specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py:

```
# settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.YourModel'
```

You also have to specify `USERNAME_FIELD` on your user model and `set_password` method for default `authenticate` function to be useful.

Usually, the best practice is not to override the default model completely, but rather extend `AbstractBaseUser` abstract model with your fields.

Read more in django docs about customizing an authentication: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/